# How to read data received from server using socket in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, sockets

I'm trying to send data from a server to client,so I wrote this little program:
server.js:

```
    var http=require("http");
var express=require("express");
var app=express();
var server=http.createServer(app);
var io=require("socket.io")(server);
var path=require("path");


server.listen(4000,function(){
    console.log("server listen on port 4000");
});




app.set('views',path.join(__dirname,'views'));
app.set('view engine','ejs');


app.get("/",function(req,res,next){

    res.render('client');

});

io.sockets.on("connection",function(socket){


    socket.emit("message","hello");
})
```

client.ejs:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<label class="label1">Name</label>

<script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
var socket=io.connect();

socket.on("message",function(message){


    $('.label1').text(message);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run my server and I test my program,the label value didn't change.Can anyone told me what is my mistake?

Comment: You're not bringing in jQuery...

Comment: Should I add jQuery??

Comment: You're using jQuery query syntax (`$('.label1')`), so yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you use jQuery in your HTML (`$('.label1')`, `$` is jQuery), you need to add jQuery library:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>

<title>test</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<label class="label1">Name</label>

<script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
var socket=io.connect();

socket.on("message",function(message){


    $('.label1').text(message);
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Also, is a good practice that, when something does not work, look at the console (F12) and understand the error.